# What happens if the flash part of a SSHD dies?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware-failure

I want to buy a new laptop but I am skeptical about the SSHD.

My question is, **what happens if the SSD part dies**? Will the SSHD and the laptop continue to work, or not?

If it makes any difference, [this](http://www.e-lenovo.gr/index.php?route=product/product&path=&product_id=891) is the Lenovo I want to buy, it has Windows 10 (the site is in Greek, but you can still get the basic features).

Thank you

Comment: That would depend on the details of design and exactly how the device fails. Hardware failures don't follow any set of rules. Bottom line -  there is no way of knowing.

Comment: The mechanical part will most likely fail a lot earlier. No need to worry. There’s probably no general answer either, like LMiller7 indicated.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases no, you will not be able to use the SSHD. It depends on the failure but:

- If the electronics portions die, there will be no communication (there is no fail over channel)
- If the storage dies, the SSHD will still try to write there and you may get data corruption, error or other issue

Bottom line is that SSD is now much more reliable and you should not be afraid. I would never go back to spinning HD in my laptops due to the speed, noise, heat, battery consumption etc.